# How to fix pagination first page load all data but onclick rest button load correctly in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, pagination

First part of my code:

```
const Inventory = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [pageCount,setPageCount] = useState(0);
  //console.log(pageCount);
  const [page,setPage] = useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();



  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/products?page=${page}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setProducts(data));
  }, [products,page]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/product-count')
   .then((res) => {
      const productCount = res?.data?.count;
     //console.log("count product",count);
     const pages = Math.ceil(productCount/6);
     setPageCount(pages);
   })
     
 },[page])
```

Return section, this code will return pagination:

```
 <div className="pagination">
                {
                    [...Array(pageCount).keys()]
                    .map(number => <button key={number} className={page===number? 'selected': 'pagination'}
                      onClick={()=> setPage(number)}
                    >
                      {number+1}
                    </button>)
                  }
                  
         </div>
```

And this is the server-side code:

```
app.get("/products",async(req,res)=>{
        const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
        //console.log(page);
        const q = {};
        const cursor = productCollection.find(q);
        
        let result;
            if(page){
                 result = await cursor.skip(page * 6).limit(6).toArray();
            }
            else{
                result = await cursor.toArray();
            }
            res.send(result);
    })
// get product count
    app.get("/product-count",async(req,res)=>{
        const query = {};
        const count = await productCollection.countDocuments(query);
        res.json({count});
    })
```

I want to load 6 data on the first load. But when data loads it displays all data. When I click the pagination button it works fine except the 1st button.

Answer (score 0):

During the first load your front-end is sending `page=0` to your backend.

In your server-side code you've the following statement: `if (page)`
But `page` will always be `false` when `page=0`, because 0 is a falsy value in javascript. So your statement always return the `else` block.

You need to change the statement to:
`if (page !== undefined)`

Comment: Thanks. It fixed my issue. And yes I also think first that I am sending default value 0 . Then I try to solve this by changing the default value 1 in the frontend part but this solution did not work.